# How to check if a name is not equal to something not to print it in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to check if the category name is not equal to `'DETALLES DE COMPRA '` to print the categories, I want to be able to do this

```
@foreach($product->items['lists'] as $category)                                    
    @if($category['category']->type == 'list')
        <div class="row pb-1">
            @if($category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA' ||
                $category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA ')

                    <p class="uppercase">
                        <strong> {{ $category['category']->name }} </strong>
                    </p>
                    @foreach($category['fields'] as $list)
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: small;
                            list-style-position: inside; padding-left: 0">
                                {{ $list['value'] }}
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This isn't working, but if the if statement is like this then it works.

```
@if($category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA ')
```

And just this doesn't work either

```
@if($category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA')
```

I would like to check for either, with the space after the name and without the space. How can I check for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
 @if($category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA' ||
                $category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA ')
```

is determining if a doesn't equal b *OR* if a doesn't equal c. You want:

```
 @if($category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA' &&
                $category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA ')
```

a shouldn't equal b *and* a shouldn't equal c.

An easier way to to do this is to just trim a before the comparison:

```
@if(trim($category['category']->name) !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the operator && instead ||.

The reason is because the operator || check if one of the conditions are true, and if one of the condition is true, enter the code block.

The operator && check if all the conditions are true, and if only one condition is false, doesn't enter to the code block.

So, your condition must be:

```
@if($category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA' &&
                $category['category']->name !== 'DETALLES DE COMPRA ')
```